# rune one query for multiple ranges in BETWEEN clause in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using the below sql query in oracle to get the count of rows in a range which works fine

```
SELECT count(SERIALNR)
  FROM my_tab
 WHERE SERIALNR BETWEEN '93266070760000' AND '93266070809999';
```

but how the query could be done if i have to run one query for multiple ranges like the below all in one query

```
93266070560000  93266070609999
93266070610000  93266070659999
93266070660000  93266070709999
93266070710000  93266070759999
93266070760000  93266070809999
```

NOTE: the Type of `SERIALNR` is `NUMBER`

Comment: Is serialnr really a `VARCHAR`? Then you might be in for a surprise with the `between` operator.

Comment: it is ``NUMBER(19)``

Comment: Then why are you comparing it to a string?

Comment: what should be the correct where clause?

Comment: Get rid of the single quotes `'93266070760000'` is a string/varchar value, `93266070760000` is a number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem needing `UNION ALL` to get each range seperately

```
SELECT 'Range 1' AS "Range", count (SERIALNR) AS "Count"
  FROM tab
 WHERE SERIALNR BETWEEN 93266070560000 AND 93266070809999
 UNION ALL 
SELECT 'Range 2', count (SERIALNR)
  FROM tab
 WHERE SERIALNR BETWEEN 93266070610000 AND 93266070659999
 UNION ALL 
SELECT 'Range 3', count (SERIALNR)
  FROM tab
 WHERE SERIALNR BETWEEN 93266070660000 AND 93266070709999
 UNION ALL 
SELECT 'Range 4', count (SERIALNR)
  FROM tab
 WHERE SERIALNR BETWEEN 93266070710000 AND 93266070759999
 UNION ALL 
SELECT 'Range 5', count (SERIALNR)
  FROM tab
 WHERE SERIALNR BETWEEN 93266070760000 AND 93266070809999
```

and you don't need to quote of `SERIALNR` as having numeric data type.

Answer (score 0):

What about multiple or conditons -

```
SELECT  count (SERIALNR)
FROM my_tab
WHERE (SERIALNR BETWEEN '93266070760000' AND   '93266070809999'
       OR SERIALNR BETWEEN '93266070560000' AND   '93266070609999'
       OR SERIALNR BETWEEN '93266070610000' AND   '93266070659999'
       OR SERIALNR BETWEEN '93266070660000' AND   '93266070709999'
       OR SERIALNR BETWEEN '93266070710000' AND   '93266070759999'
       OR SERIALNR BETWEEN '93266070760000' AND   '93266070809999');
```

Comment: this gives the count of the first condition. i.e SERIALNR BETWEEN '93266070760000' AND   '93266070809999'. i want the count of each and every range indivisually

Answer (score 0):

You have use `OR` clause,

```
SELECT  count (SERIALNR) FROM my_tab WHERE 
(SERIALNR  BETWEEN '93266070760000' AND   '93266070809999')
OR
(SERIALNR  BETWEEN '93266070610000' AND   '93266070659999')
OR
(SERIALNR  BETWEEN '93266070660000' AND   '93266070709999')
OR
(SERIALNR  BETWEEN '93266070710000' AND   '93266070759999')
OR
(SERIALNR  BETWEEN '93266070760000' AND   '93266070809999');
```

If these values are stored in any other table, it would be more convenient

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to user braces between each statement conditioning with `OR` like below

```
( 
  SERIALNR BETWEEN '93266070760000' AND   '93266070809999'
  OR
..... other ranges comes here
) and
OTHER cONDITIONS
```

You can see the documentation about [logical conditions](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/conditions004.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for conditional aggregation, if you want the counts in columns:

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(CASE WHEN serialnr BETWEEN '93266070760000' AND '93266070809999' THEN 1 END) AS c1,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN serialnr BETWEEN '93266070610000' AND '93266070659999' THEN 1 END) AS c2,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN serialnr BETWEEN '93266070660000' AND '93266070709999' THEN 1 END) AS c3,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN serialnr BETWEEN '93266070710000' AND '93266070759999' THEN 1 END) AS c4,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN serialnr BETWEEN '93266070760000' AND '93266070809999' THEN 1 END) AS c5
FROM my_tab 
WHERE serialnr BETWEEN '93266070560000' AND '93266070809999';
```

Or for `UNION ALL`, if you want the counts in rows:

```
WITH ranges AS
(
  SELECT '93266070760000' AS s1, '93266070809999' AS s2 FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '93266070610000' AS s1, '93266070659999' AS s2 FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '93266070660000' AS s1, '93266070709999' AS s2 FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '93266070710000' AS s1, '93266070759999' AS s2 FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '93266070760000' AS s1, '93266070809999' AS s2 FROM DUAL
)
SELECT
  s1,
  s2,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_tab WHERE serialnr BETWEEN r.s1 AND r.s2) AS cnt
FROM ranges r
ORDER BY s1;
```

Answer (score 0):

@thorsten or instead of all the unionall statements, maybe something like this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN serialnr BETWEEN '93266070760000' AND '93266070809999' THEN c1
            WHEN serialnr BETWEEN '93266070610000' AND '93266070659999' THEN c2 
            WHEN serialnr BETWEEN '93266070660000' AND '93266070709999' THEN c3 
            WHEN serialnr BETWEEN '93266070710000' AND '93266070759999' THEN c4 
            WHEN serialnr BETWEEN '93266070760000' AND '93266070809999' THEN c5 
            end Category, count(serialnr) total
FROM my_tab 
group by CASE WHEN serialnr BETWEEN '93266070760000' AND '93266070809999' THEN c1
              WHEN serialnr BETWEEN '93266070610000' AND '93266070659999' THEN c2 
              WHEN serialnr BETWEEN '93266070660000' AND '93266070709999' THEN c3 
              WHEN serialnr BETWEEN '93266070710000' AND '93266070759999' THEN c4 
              WHEN serialnr BETWEEN '93266070760000' AND '93266070809999' THEN c5 
              end;
```

I'm not certain which is more efficient though: